# Change font in a single paragraph Arabxetex

Tags: fonts, arabxetex

I'm wondering how to change the font in juste a single paragraph inside `\begin{arab}` environnement. My default font is setted like so `\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Scheherazade}`, i also use polyglossia package along with arabxetex.

Comment: Welcome to  TeX SX! Probably defining another `\newfontfamily\some_font_command{fontname}` and switching to this other font with `\some_font_command` should be enough.

Comment: tried so, but when applied inside a `begin{arab}` environnement the text is not parsed though.

Comment: but when i use new font declaration with just arabic text pasted it work even inside arab environnement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's two ways of doing it.

The easiest way is to put your paragraphs in separate `arab` environments then change the definition of `\arabicfont` before the `arab` environment then back again afterwards.

(BTW, I don't know what the Arabic says, I copied out of the `araxetex` manual.)

**MWE 1:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\scheherazadefont{Scheherazade}[Script=Arabic]
\newfontfamily\amirifont{Amiri}[Script=Arabic]
\let\arabicfont\scheherazadefont
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\section*{Changing fonts between \texttt{arab} environments}
\begin{arab}
  'amruN, 'ibiluN, 'u_htuN, '"u_ht"uN, '"Uql"Id"Is, ra'suN, 'ar'asu,
  sa'ala, qara'a, bu'suN, 'ab'usuN, ra'ufa, ru'asA'u, bi'ruN, 'as'ilaTuN,
  ka'iba, qA'imuN, ri'AsaTuN, su'ila, samA'uN, barI'uN, sU'uN, bad'uN,
  ^say'uN, ^say'iN, ^say'aN, sA'ala, mas'alaTuN, saw'aTuN, _ha.tI'aTuN,
  jA'a, ridA'uN, ridA'aN, jI'a, radI'iN, sU'uN, .daw'uN, qay'iN, .zim'aN
  , yatasA'alUna, 'a`dA'akum, 'a`dA'ikum, 'a`dA'ukum maqrU'aT, mU'ibAt,
  taw'am, yas'alu, 'a.sdiq^A'uh_u, ya^g^I'u, s^U'ila
\end{arab}
\let\arabicfont\amirifont
\begin{arab}
  'amruN, 'ibiluN, 'u_htuN, '"u_ht"uN, '"Uql"Id"Is, ra'suN, 'ar'asu,
  sa'ala, qara'a, bu'suN, 'ab'usuN, ra'ufa, ru'asA'u, bi'ruN, 'as'ilaTuN,
  ka'iba, qA'imuN, ri'AsaTuN, su'ila, samA'uN, barI'uN, sU'uN, bad'uN,
  ^say'uN, ^say'iN, ^say'aN, sA'ala, mas'alaTuN, saw'aTuN, _ha.tI'aTuN,
  jA'a, ridA'uN, ridA'aN, jI'a, radI'iN, sU'uN, .daw'uN, qay'iN, .zim'aN
  , yatasA'alUna, 'a`dA'akum, 'a`dA'ikum, 'a`dA'ukum maqrU'aT, mU'ibAt,
  taw'am, yas'alu, 'a.sdiq^A'uh_u, ya^g^I'u, s^U'ila
\end{arab}
\let\arabicfont\scheherazadefont
\begin{arab}
  'amruN, 'ibiluN, 'u_htuN, '"u_ht"uN, '"Uql"Id"Is, ra'suN, 'ar'asu,
  sa'ala, qara'a, bu'suN, 'ab'usuN, ra'ufa, ru'asA'u, bi'ruN, 'as'ilaTuN,
  ka'iba, qA'imuN, ri'AsaTuN, su'ila, samA'uN, barI'uN, sU'uN, bad'uN,
  ^say'uN, ^say'iN, ^say'aN, sA'ala, mas'alaTuN, saw'aTuN, _ha.tI'aTuN,
  jA'a, ridA'uN, ridA'aN, jI'a, radI'iN, sU'uN, .daw'uN, qay'iN, .zim'aN
  , yatasA'alUna, 'a`dA'akum, 'a`dA'ikum, 'a`dA'ukum maqrU'aT, mU'ibAt,
  taw'am, yas'alu, 'a.sdiq^A'uh_u, ya^g^I'u, s^U'ila
\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The other option is to define a command to change the font within the `arab` environment which deals with the encoding. I think the output is the same, but I've included screen shots just in case.

**MWE 2:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Scheherazade}[Script=Arabic]
\newfontfamily\amirifont{Amiri}[Script=Arabic]
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setarabfont}[1]{%
  #1
  \ifax@mode@defined%
    \ifx\@tempa\ax@mode@trans%
      \arabtex@codes\ax@trans@style%
      \addfontfeature{Mapping=arabtex-trans-\ax@trans@convention}%
    \else
      \ifx\@tempa\ax@mode@utf%
        \utf@fontfeature%
      \else
        \arabtex@codes%
        \addfontfeature{Mapping=arabtex-\@tempa}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \else
    \PackageWarning{arabxetex}{Mode \@tempa\ not defined, defaulting to \@ax@mode}%
    \arabtex@codes%
    \addfontfeature{Mapping=arabtex-\ax@mode}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\section*{Changing fonts within the \texttt{arab} environment}
\begin{arab}
  'amruN, 'ibiluN, 'u_htuN, '"u_ht"uN, '"Uql"Id"Is, ra'suN, 'ar'asu,
  sa'ala, qara'a, bu'suN, 'ab'usuN, ra'ufa, ru'asA'u, bi'ruN, 'as'ilaTuN,
  ka'iba, qA'imuN, ri'AsaTuN, su'ila, samA'uN, barI'uN, sU'uN, bad'uN,
  ^say'uN, ^say'iN, ^say'aN, sA'ala, mas'alaTuN, saw'aTuN, _ha.tI'aTuN,
  jA'a, ridA'uN, ridA'aN, jI'a, radI'iN, sU'uN, .daw'uN, qay'iN, .zim'aN
  , yatasA'alUna, 'a`dA'akum, 'a`dA'ikum, 'a`dA'ukum maqrU'aT, mU'ibAt,
  taw'am, yas'alu, 'a.sdiq^A'uh_u, ya^g^I'u, s^U'ila

  \setarabfont{\amirifont}
  'amruN, 'ibiluN, 'u_htuN, '"u_ht"uN, '"Uql"Id"Is, ra'suN, 'ar'asu,
  sa'ala, qara'a, bu'suN, 'ab'usuN, ra'ufa, ru'asA'u, bi'ruN, 'as'ilaTuN,
  ka'iba, qA'imuN, ri'AsaTuN, su'ila, samA'uN, barI'uN, sU'uN, bad'uN,
  ^say'uN, ^say'iN, ^say'aN, sA'ala, mas'alaTuN, saw'aTuN, _ha.tI'aTuN,
  jA'a, ridA'uN, ridA'aN, jI'a, radI'iN, sU'uN, .daw'uN, qay'iN, .zim'aN
  , yatasA'alUna, 'a`dA'akum, 'a`dA'ikum, 'a`dA'ukum maqrU'aT, mU'ibAt,
  taw'am, yas'alu, 'a.sdiq^A'uh_u, ya^g^I'u, s^U'ila

  \setarabfont{\arabicfont}
  'amruN, 'ibiluN, 'u_htuN, '"u_ht"uN, '"Uql"Id"Is, ra'suN, 'ar'asu,
  sa'ala, qara'a, bu'suN, 'ab'usuN, ra'ufa, ru'asA'u, bi'ruN, 'as'ilaTuN,
  ka'iba, qA'imuN, ri'AsaTuN, su'ila, samA'uN, barI'uN, sU'uN, bad'uN,
  ^say'uN, ^say'iN, ^say'aN, sA'ala, mas'alaTuN, saw'aTuN, _ha.tI'aTuN,
  jA'a, ridA'uN, ridA'aN, jI'a, radI'iN, sU'uN, .daw'uN, qay'iN, .zim'aN
  , yatasA'alUna, 'a`dA'akum, 'a`dA'ikum, 'a`dA'ukum maqrU'aT, mU'ibAt,
  taw'am, yas'alu, 'a.sdiq^A'uh_u, ya^g^I'u, s^U'ila
\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

[image]